# Removing elements from a list and modifying another list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `CB` containing many sublists with numpy arrays. I want to identify the empty lists and generate a new list `J_new` by removing the specific element. I present the current and expected output.

```
import numpy as np
arJ_new=[]
CB = [[[]], [np.array([9.75016872e-05]), np.array([0.00019793]), np.array([0.0001007])], [np.array([0.0002704])]]
J=[32,1,35]

for i in range(0,len(CB)):
    if len(CB[i])!=0:
        J_new=J[i]
        arJ_new.append(J_new)
        J_new=list(arJ_new)
print(J_new)
```

The current output is

```
[32, 1, 35]
```

The expected output is

```
[1,35]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By means of `numpy` (check size) filtering:

```
j_new = [J[i] for i, a in enumerate(CB) if np.array(a).size != 0]
```

---

```
[1, 35]
```